# What is the easiest mail server setup for piping incoming mails to scripts *only*?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, exim, osticket

I want to set up a ticketing system (osTicket) on a centOS server that generates tickets from incoming e-mails.

osTicket can query mailboxes, but [it also provides an API / scripts for piping](https://docs.osticket.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Email%20Piping.html). Is there a recommended way to setup a (lightweight) mailserver to pipe incoming emails to the script? I do not need actual mailboxes for users.

It's been a while since I did any work on a mail server, but it seems to me that I would only need to set up an MTA for this, and no MDA, correct?

My fallback is to set up POP3/SMTP inboxes elsewhere and query from osTicket. Easy as that would be, the local MTA setup seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using remote mailbox accessible via IMAP with IMAP `IDLE` command support.
It will allow you to get "near real time" delivery to pipe without burden of configuring **properly** your own SMTP server.
[AFAIR IMAP IDLE is supported e.g. by gmail]

You may use `fetchmail` with custom procmail script as mda (no need for local SMTP/MTA server).
Using `procmail` (as "man in the middle) is not strictly necessary but your it will allow you to easily run filtering before delivery to the ticket system (e.g. anti-spam + anti-virus).